# jQuery parseXML, .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to parse my xml using jquery to make a table. I have this code bellow. I am trying to make it loop through the  tags, however the loop isnt working, and I dont think anything inside the loop is being run.
I am 80% sure my xml is correct, as when looking for any tag, without .each(), it will output all but just not separated. Anyone have any advice on what I am doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("xml.xml", function(data, status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      xmlDoc = $.parseXML( data ),
      $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
      var data2 = $xml.find("name").text());
      jQuery(xml).find("films").each(function()
                 {
                  movieId = jQuery(this).find("id").text();
                  alert(movieId);
                 });
```

Here is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:films xmlns:ns2="xml.jaxb.model">
    <filmList>
        <films>
            <id>11003</id>
            <name>THE ADVENTURES OF PRISCILLA, QUEEN OF THE DESERT</name>
            <year>1994</year>
            <director>STEPHEN ELLIOTT</director>
            <stars>TERENCE STAMP, GUY PEARCE</stars>
            <review>Whimsical and warm-hearted tale of three Australian drag queens as they drive through the Australian outback on their way to the city. Stopping in small towns to refuel Priscilla, their bus, they start to give performances to the sometimes amazed, sometimes entranced townsfolk. Stamp, Hugo Weaving and Guy Pearce (L.A.Confidential) are terrific in their roles.</review>
        </films>
        <films>
            <id>11099</id>
            <name>THE Lion QUEEN</name>
            <year>1993</year>
            <director>ROGER ALLERS &amp; ROB MINKOFF</director>
            <stars>ANIMATED</stars>
            <review>The most successful Disney film ever, and rightly so. A superbly animated tale with stirring visuals and good songs. A young lion returns to the pride to claim his title as The Lion King after discovering his father was killed by his evil uncle. Score by Sir Tim Rice and Elton John, with the Oscar winning Can You Feel The Love Tonight.</review>
        </films>
    </filmList>
</ns2:films>
```

Comment: You have an extra `)` on this line: `var data2 = $xml.find("name").text());` That should be causing a syntax error.

Comment: You can't have `var` after `,`. Why are you separating your statements with `,` instead of `;` anyway?

Comment: There's no way any of the code you posted could be running, so I don't think you copied it correctly. Please post correct code.

Comment: `jQuery(xml)` should be `$xml`. There's no variable `xml` in your code.

Comment: And you don't need to call `jQuery()` again, you made it a jQuery object when you assigned `$xml`.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar's comments say your code would be not running and seems like you may have copy pasted the wrong thing. However, something along these lines should cover what you need.

The code itself is pretty explanatory, though feel free to ask any questions about it.

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:films xmlns:ns2="xml.jaxb.model"><filmList><films><id>11003</id><name>THE ADVENTURES OF PRISCILLA, QUEEN OF THE DESERT</name><year>1994</year><director>STEPHEN ELLIOTT</director><stars>TERENCE STAMP, GUY PEARCE</stars><review>Whimsical and warm-hearted tale of three Australian drag queens as they drive through the Australian outback on their way to the city. Stopping in small towns to refuel Priscilla, their bus, they start to give performances to the sometimes amazed, sometimes entranced townsfolk. Stamp, Hugo Weaving and Guy Pearce (L.A.Confidential) are terrific in their roles.</review></films><films><id>11099</id><name>THE Lion QUEEN</name><year>1993</year><director>ROGER ALLERS &amp; ROB MINKOFF</director><stars>ANIMATED</stars><review>The most successful Disney film ever, and rightly so. A superbly animated tale with stirring visuals and good songs. A young lion returns to the pride to claim his title as The Lion King after discovering his father was killed by his evil uncle. Score by Sir Tim Rice and Elton John, with the Oscar winning Can You Feel The Love Tonight.</review></films></filmList></ns2:films>'
var parsedDoc = $.parseXML(xml)
var parsed = $(parsedDoc)
parsed.find("films").each(function(i, item)
{
  console.log("Movie Id:" + $(item).find("id").text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this code and it works, so I've tried getting my xml using $.get and this seems to be causing the problem.